# Auto pull when test pass

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to setup Azure DevOps such that:

- There is one main branch
- There is a dev branch

Now whenever a developer pushes to the dev branch, if the test pipeline passes, the changes are pulled into the main branch.

We're a small team, we don't want to create a pull request for every change, but we'd like for some tests to pass before the merge.

Comment: If principal used by your build agent has enough permissions on your repo/branch, you could run a script to merge local dev into local main and push to remote main.

Comment: Sounds like you should adopt a simpler branching model and eliminate the `dev` branch entirely. Run your tests as part of the PR.

Comment: No PR, no code review, no personal clone, just push to dev. This is not for big projects.

Comment: I suggest incorporating the git checkout and git merge steps into your CI/CD pipeline for the dev branch, which you may create."